# Calculate ignores outer Filter context

Tags: powerbi, dax

I already posted this question in die power bi community some time ago and revisited my question today. Since I still cannot wrap my head around it I thought I'd ask it here again.

Original: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Calculate-ignores-outer-Filter-context/m-p/1933884#M737076

here is the quesion (again):

After searching "running total" and "filter context" I couldn't find something that matches my question (in a reasonable time).

My base Idea was to compute a running total in DAX. I have a fact table

[facts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ir72F.png)

and a calendar table (marked as such)

[calender-table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Khvsq.png)

The "is_this_year" flag marks the current year (2021) with 1, otherwise 0. So the dates start in early 2019.

The setup is as follows: I have a page-level filter on "is_this_year":

[page-level-filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DW1SI.png)

and I wrote the following Measure:

```
theMeasure = 
   VAR cur_max = MAX ( 'Calendar'[Date] )
   RETURN
      CALCULATE ( MIN ( 'Calendar'[Date] ), 'Calendar'[Date] <= cur_max )
```

Because of the Page-level filter I assument that I would get 1.1.2021 for every row but instead I get this:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Deos.png)
This lookes like the page-level filter is ignored.

My reasoning here is that in the DAX generated in Power BI I get a filter on Calendar[is_this_year] which is essentially a table

| is_this_year |
| --- |
| 1 |

In the measure itself I modify the filter context and add a filter on the [Date] Column of the calendar table. My understanding of filter contexts was that, because those filters are applied on different columns they should exist side by side, meaning we have the following filters in the final filter context:
[is_this_year] = 1
[Date] <= 5.5.2021 (for example)
So I would expect to get a row like this:

| Date | The measure |
| --- | --- |
| 05.05.2021 | 01.01.2021 |

But I we can see in the picture above I get 03.01.2019 as a measure value.

Can someone help me understand this?

I do see that the Solution posted in the original question works, yet I do not see why I need to pass the filter again.
The solution was:

```
theMeasure = 
VAR cur_max = MAX ( 'Calendar'[Date] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( MIN ( 'Calendar'[Date] ),  'Calendar'[Date] <= cur_max, VALUES('Calendar'[is_this_year]) )
```

example file here:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtFejN9ixXnChShZpu7MiEgoXVw5?e=ZCdERm

Thank You! I hope someone can shed some light here :)